# PHP sockets, tell when the connection has died due to server going offline

Tags: php, sockets

I am currently, in php, using non-blocking socket to connect to a service, I am having trouble telling when the connection has dropped due to server side going down... All i get as errors are 10035 which is a non-fatal error which i ignore, but i never get the appropriate error and therefore have not been able to tell when the connection has dropped due to the server closing... any suggestions on this matter?

My listening routine looks like so

```
$this->shouldListen = true;
$fullResponse = '';

while ($this->shouldListen) {

  //read some data
  $tempResponse=socket_read($this->sock,1000);
  if ($this->shouldBeRunning() == false) {
    break;
  }

  if ($tempResponse == FALSE) {
    //ignore ignorable error 
    $error = socket_last_error($this->sock);
    if ($error!=11 && $error!=115 && $error!=10035) {
      $this->writeLogFile("got an error ".$error);
      break;
    }
  } else {
    //do something with the response
  }

}
```

and create the socket connection like so

```
function connect() {

  /* Turn on implicit output flushing so we see what we're getting
   * as it comes in. */
  ob_implicit_flush();

  if (($this->sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) === false) {
    return false;
    // echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
  } else {
    //echo 'success1<br />';
  }

  if (socket_bind($this->sock, '0.0.0.0') === false) {
    return false;
    //echo "socket_bind() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
  } else {
    //echo 'success2<br />';
  }

  if (socket_connect($this->sock, $this->ip, $this->port) === false) {
    //echo "socket_connect() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
    return false;
  } else {
    //echo 'success3<br />';
  }

  socket_set_nonblock($this->sock);
  return true;
}
```

Thanks

Daniel

Comment: @Pekka just posted the code i use for listening and to create the socket connection

Comment: This is one of the reasons I prefer using `fsockopen()` or `stream_socket_*()` because then you can just call `feof()` on the resource to detect closed streams. Of course, if the server goes down and doesn't send a `FIN` or `RST`, there is nothing you can do to detect it, and you just have to implement a timeout/keepalive/ACK system.

Comment: @DaveRandom so your approach would work if the server were to send an FIN or RST correct? So if the server program just crashes for some reason then this approach would not work correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct. The other advantage of using streams over sockets is that they are more readily available. Many servers don't have sockets, but most of them do have streams. What type of service are you connecting to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We work with a number of remote services where we have to incorporate 'ping' methods to test whether the service to which we are connected still has an active connection. I would recommend implementing this ping concept within your script.

Someone has posted a utility ping method, using the socket_* library, on PHP's [socket_create](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-create.php) page.

Comment: yea, i thought of doing something like this if nothing else comes up